# How to draw rectangle on the website to highlight?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Is there any way to implement a Google feedback like feature [as shown here](http://www.google.com/tools/feedback/intl/en/learnmore.html)? We can make the website slightly black-out using CSS, but how can we draw a rectangle on the that particular interface like highlighting some text or error. We can use same concept like sprite cow, has used to highlight the rectangle on particular image [link](http://www.spritecow.com/). Any kind of idea and source is welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Are you just looking to create the effect or are you trying to mimic some of the underlying functionality as well? If you look at it in the chrome debugger its clear that there's a really complicated system being used underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked myself this question recently and when looking at it through the chrome debugger it would appear that they are using some techniques that are more advanced than just sectioning off the screen into highlighted and un-highlighted areas.

The first thing to notice is that google uses 5 iframes to acheive their feedback system.

`google-feedback-mask-frame`
: This is used just for the mask, it covers the whole screen. I'm not sure why they chose to use a whole iframe for this. But it serves the purpose of making sure you dont click any page links in feedback mode

`google-feedback-screenshot-frame`
:This is where the real magic happens I suspect. It contains a copy of the page you were viewing, but with some proprietary HTML tags (`<gft></gft>`) to let the script know where highlight-able content is (images, text, links, etc.)

`google-feedback-feedback-frame`
: This holds the controls for the highlighted areas as well as the X button for the whole widget.

To pull off the effect google actually does use a bunch of sections like @Jani Hartikainen suggests. 
In the screenshot below you can see that when you have multiple selections there's quite a few div's that need to be created to accommodate the effect.

[image]

I'm sure there's a very complicated algorithm for figuring out where all the div's go, but that's what makes software dev fun right??

`google-feedback-proxy-frame` 
: has the controls that you see in the bottom right side.

`google-feedback-render-frame`
: This one is a bit more mysterious, all it contains is a script called render_frame.js which is obviously obfuscated and illegible.

In conclusion, using sections IS the way that google does it but there's a lot more magic that allows them to auto-highlight links and images. If you find out more I'm really interested too so let me know!

Answer (score 7):

The most straightforward way to do this is, probably, to just have a div that are created when you drag the mouse over the page.

I suspect Google does it using something like this:

- Draw a slightly dimmed div ("dimmer") on top of the whole page
- When the user clicks and drags on the dimmer, they split it in multiple divs like this:

  ```
  ### | ## | ###
  ----+----+----
  ### |    | ###
  ----+----+----
  ### | ## | ###
  ```
- In the above, the center area is the area the user was dragging over
- The center area is now empty, and you can see the site through it, because the dimmer was split into 8 smaller divs.
- While the user keeps the mouse button held down, the script keeps resizing the split dimmer divs to accommodate the rectangular area the user has dragged.

(It might also omit the extra divs I included in the diagram, so that it only has one div above, and one div below, the rectangle since it would work without them too)

Comment: :-D, Excellent logic. Thanks.

Comment: but the question is...how do you take the snapshot ?

Comment: @TheBrain While not familiar with how google does it, the easiest way to do this would be to provide some sort of admin view on the page. Then, when on the page, a script is used to render the rectangles in the positions the users drew them on. Alternatively they might take a snapshot of the page using some server side tool. I saw some command line usable tool for this but sadly forgot the name. @A.P.S you should accept the answer if you're happy with it. If not, please specify if you actually wanted something else :)

Comment: Actually if we use any thumbnail api to get the snapshot of entire process after drawing rectangle, will be quite good. But all the API render the html in memory and get the set the server side snapshot not client side. that is the main issue. I have posted the code for drawing rectangle on webpage, but it is quite basic, try to take snapshot of it and see if the following rectangles are comming in picture. Thanks ;-D

Comment: @A.P.S The example you posted seems to work. If you store the absolute X/Y/width/height details of the rectangles, you should be able to first render the page on server side to an image, and then render rectangles on the image (for example using the GD or Imagick functionality in PHP)

Answer (score 1):

Sample code working on all browser, just draw rectangle with mouse click, but give some highlight flicking in chrome, didn't find any solution to it :-C....

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Draw on Web</title>
<style type="text/css">
.square {
        border: 3px solid #FF0000;
        position: absolute;
}
.black_overlay{
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0%;
            left: 0%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: black;
            z-index:1001;
            -moz-opacity: 0.1;
            opacity:.10;
            filter: alpha(opacity=10);
        }
.white_content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 25%;
            left: 25%;
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
            padding: 16px;
            border: 16px solid orange;
            background-color: white;
            z-index:1002;
            overflow: auto;
        }
</style>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var d;
    var posx;
    var posy;
    var initx=false;
    var inity=false
    function getMouse(obj,e){
        posx=0;
        posy=0;
        var ev=(!e)?window.event:e;//Moz:IE
        if (ev.pageX){//Moz
            posx=ev.pageX+window.pageXOffset;
            posy=ev.pageY+window.pageYOffset;
        }
        else if(ev.clientX){//IE
            posx=ev.clientX+document.body.scrollLeft;
            posy=ev.clientY+document.body.scrollTop;
        }
        else{
            return false
        }//old browsers
        obj.onmousedown=function(){
            initx=posx; inity=posy;
            d = document.createElement('div');
            d.className='square'
            d.style.left=initx+'px';d.style.top=inity+'px';
            //d.style.background='#434343';
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(d)
        }
        obj.onmouseup=function(){initx=false;inity=false;}
            if(initx){
            d.style.width=Math.abs(posx-initx)+'px';d.style.height=Math.abs(posy-inity)+'px';
            d.style.left=posx-initx<0?posx+'px':initx+'px';
            d.style.top=posy-inity<0?posy+'px':inity+'px';
        }
    }

    document.onmousemove=function(event){
    getMouse(document,event);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="mailto:someone@$nailmail.com" ENCTYPE="text/plain">
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2>
<tr>
<td colspan=2>
<font size=2 face="arial" color="#000000">
<INPUT type="text" name=URL size=17 value="http://"> :Your URL<BR>
<INPUT type="text" name=user size=17> :Your Username<BR>
<INPUT type="text" name=email size=17> :Your E-mail
</font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<font size=1 face="arial" color="#000000">
<INPUT name=subscribe type=radio value="yes" CHECKED> subscribe<BR>
<INPUT name=subscribe type=radio value="no"> unsubscribe<BR>
</font>
</td>
<td>
<SELECT name="choices" size=1>
<OPTION selected> OPTIONS
<OPTION> OPTION 1
<OPTION> OPTION 2
<OPTION> OPTION 3
<OPTION> OPTION 4
<OPTION> OPTION 5
</SELECT>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2>
<font size=1 face="arial" color="#000000">
<INPUT type=checkbox name="html" value="sendme" CHECKED>
i can recive email as html<BR>
<INPUT type=checkbox name="receipt" value="sendme">
send me a recipt for this email<BR>
</font>
<TEXTAREA cols=20 rows=10>
Hey !
what do you think of the form?

cool huh?
</TEXTAREA><br>
<center>
<INPUT NAME="redirect" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="index.html">
<INPUT NAME="NEXT_URL" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="index.html">
<INPUT type=submit value=Send>
<INPUT type=reset value="Clear">
</center>
</td></tr></table>
</FORM>
&nbsp;
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with the Canvas element.

Comment: Thanks, I have achieved it using Canvas and JavaScript. Got help from various links. http://thinkvitamin.com/code/how-to-draw-with-html-5-canvas/ and http://diveintohtml5.org/canvas.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/Special:Tags?tag=Canvas+tutorial . Just doing it for IE using http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/. :-P

Comment: On IE you can use SVG, I think there's a library that does the canvas to SVG conversion, I remember using something like it once. You'll have to look for it though, as I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Tools has a nice little tool called ["Expose"](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/toolbox/expose/index.html), I used it a few months ago and it worked great for me...simple, extensible, and it just works.